# Why do we retain A->.aA,a/b in I3 stage of LALR parsing of S->AA, A->aA|B?

Tags: compilers, parsers

The question is LALR(1) parsing of the following:

```
S->AA
A->aA
A->b
```

The link to the question is on this page:https://www.javatpoint.com/lalr-1-parsing

My question concerns I3, where despite a being read there is another production A->aA, a/b, where the a is *not* read.

I wish to know the reasons for this. If anyone can clarify it to me, please help. Why is this extra production there?

Comment: The position of the points differ. In one production, the point precedes `a`; in the other it precedes `A`. Only the first can shift an `a`. The other one only advances through GOTO(A). Items with different point positions are different, so they can coexist in an itemset.

Comment: I know they can coexist. What I want to know is why and how it is even there.

Comment: It's added by the closure operation, as stated in that text: "Add all productions starting with A in I3 State because • is followed by the non-terminal." Items added by closure have the • at the left edge, because the production is just starting.

Comment: I think the main advice to give here is to avoid learning non-trivial stuff from crappy tutorials. You wouldn't have this question if you've studied the material from any reasonable book (or even lecture notes) on formal languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread:

The state $I_3$ is reached by processing a SHIFT action on the item $A\to \bullet a A$, resulting in the item $A\to a\bullet A$. The original item, with the $\bullet$ at the beginning of the right-hand side, is not "retained". But the new item has the $\bullet$ immediately before the non-terminal $A$ (which happens to be the same non-terminal, but that's irrelevant). So when closure is performed on the itemset, the productions for $A$ are added, with the $\bullet$ at the beginning of each one. Thus, the itemset for $I_3$ will include both the shifted $A\to a\bullet A$ and a new $A\to \bullet aA$, along with the other production for $A$, $A\to \bullet b$.